# What is the difference between Query and QueryString in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

Can anyone tell me what is the difference between Query and QueryString in C# or Asp.Net.

Comment: No, I am confuse with both of these that's why asking the difference

Comment: `Query` usually refers to an sql select statement, while `queryString` is the part of the page's url after the question mark.

Comment: I have this statement 
empID = Request.QueryString["emp_id"];
When i Write empID=Request.
Splash screen offers many methods and properties.
It includes Query and QueryString both But when i use both i feel no difference b/w them.
Now can you please tell me the difference????

Comment: in asp.net core 3 HttpContext.Request object has Query and QueryString properties. So for me, it's a valid question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Querystrings and Queries have nothing to do in ASP.Net. Web pages can be requested with query strings. The QueryString in ASP.NET accesses this information. When you load file.html?x=y, it parses "x" and "y" and you can get the information coming in the querystring as following:

```
public partial class Default : Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string q = Request.QueryString["param"];
        if (q != null)
        {
            Response.Write("param is ");
            Response.Write(q);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks it was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with ASP.NET Core, then:

- **Request.QueryString**: Is the raw query string. for example, in `http://a.com?name=vahid&lastname=farahmandian` the `Request.QueryString` is `?name=vahid&lastname=farahmandian` which is a raw string.
- **Request.Query**: Is a query value collection parsed from `Request.QueryString`. for example in `http://a.com?name=vahid&lastname=farahmandian`, the `Request.Query` is a collection with two members:

> Member 1: Key=name and Value=vahid
>
> Member 2: Key=lastname and Value=farahmandian

Which both are parsed from `Request.QueryString`

Read More:
Request.Query: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.httprequest.query?view=aspnetcore-7.0#microsoft-aspnetcore-http-httprequest-query

Request.QueryString: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.httprequest.querystring?view=aspnetcore-7.0

Answer (score -1):

You are speaking about two different things:

**`QueryString`**:

> In the World Wide Web, a query string is the part of a uniform
>   resource locator (URL) containing data that does not fit conveniently
>   into a hierarchical path structure. The query string commonly includes
>   fields added to a base URI by a Web browser or other client
>   application, for example as part of an HTML form.

[image]

---

**`Query`**:

> Usually programmers use this word when they have a database and want
>   to have a dialog with it by some lines of commands and they call each
>   `sql` command a `query`. In database a query can be either a select
>   query or an action query. A select query is simply a data retrieval
>   query. An action query can ask for additional operations on the data,
>   such as insertion, updating or deletion.

---

You can easily obtain this information by Googling! So please first try it in this cases.